# Понимание барьеров памяти

Tags: .net, многопоточность

В .NET в классе `Thread` имеются функции `VolatileRead` и `VolatileWrite` (и аналогичные `Volatile.Read`/`Volatile.Write`):

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] // disable optimizations
public static int VolatileRead(ref int address)
{
    int ret = address;
    MemoryBarrier(); // Call MemoryBarrier to ensure the proper semantic in a portable way.
    return ret;
}

[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] // disable optimizations
public static void VolatileWrite(ref int address, int value)
{
    MemoryBarrier(); // Call MemoryBarrier to ensure the proper semantic in a portable way.
    address = value;
}
```

Не совсем понимаю, почему барьеры памяти стоят именно в этих местах. Например, в `VolatileRead`, почему не нужен барьер до чтения значения? Кроме того, эти методы не инлайнятся, неужели процессор может переставить инструкции сквозь call/ret?

Comment: Думаю, может переставить, иначе даже вызов пустой функции был бы _полным_ барьером.

Comment: @VladD да, действительно, и call, и ret могут быть переупорядочены http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261098/